# How can I focus a Textfield?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to focus a libGDX Textfield from the code without clicking on the Textfield.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was having the same question, finally found the answer by looking at TextField code.

You can focus your text field by doing this:

```
stage.setKeyboardFocus(textField);
//show the keyboard
textField.getOnscreenKeyboard().show(true);
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score -8):

replace component's name with jtextfield in following code:

```
jtextfield.requestFocus();
```

Comment: The libGDX Textfield has no .requestFocus() method.